# Open special folder view intent in old version of android

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to open special folder where user can pick only .xml file. So , I user SetDataAndType for intent . Everything works fine in new versions of android (tested api 21.. 25). But it doesn't work for api 16. Here is code what I use:

```
 var intent = new Intent();

            Android.Net.Uri contentURI = null;

            if (_existingConfig != null)
            {
                if (requestCode == ASSETS_SELECT_CODE && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_existingConfig.AssetsPath))
                {
                    contentURI = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(_existingConfig.AssetsPath));
                }
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_existingConfig.GoodsPath))
                {
                    contentURI = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(_existingConfig.GoodsPath));
                }
            }

            if (contentURI != null)
            {
                intent.SetDataAndType(contentURI, "text/xml");
            }
            else
            {
                intent.SetType("text/xml");
            }

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
            {
                intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
                StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, Resources.GetString(Resource.String.select_xml_file)),
                                        requestCode);
            }
            else
            {
                intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionOpenDocument);
                StartActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
            }
```

the same window is shown every time

[image]

Comment: Any stack trace?

Comment: nope , nothing :/

Comment: Where is the special folder?

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
    String path = "Your Path";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(getFileUri(path.trim()), getMimeType(path.trim()));
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);


    /**
      * Determine the MIME type for the document file
      *
      * @param url Complete path of the file
      * @return string type of MIME
      */
     private static String getMimeType(String url) {
         String type = null;
         String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
         if (extension != null) {
             type =           
  MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    }
    return type;
}

/**
 * Generate URI for the required Intent
 *
 * @param filePath Path of the required file
 * @return uri
 */
 private static Uri getFileUri(String filePath) {
    Uri fileUri = null;
    File file = new File(filePath);
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= BUILD_VERSION) {
            Method m = StrictMode.class.getMethod("disableDeathOnFileUriExposure");
            m.invoke(null);
        }
        fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return fileUri;
}
```